# How can you show in an ER diagram that a product can only be bought once?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, diagram

I am making an ER diagram about an online music store where customers can purchase and download music online. But I also have to make sure that they cannot buy the same track/song twice. How can you relate one entity from the other to make sure they could not download the same song?

[image]

Comment: I think you can't. ER is for showing relationship.

Comment: Is this not just a PK on the PURCHASE table for email and track_ID?

Comment: @KurtHamilton No, there isn't any PK. The PURCHASE table is an associative entity.

Comment: @Salim is that so? That means there isn't any other way?

Comment: @user707339 OK, you need a unique constraint on those two fields then

Comment: @KurtHamilton So i would add a PK like purchase_id?

Comment: @user707339 you should add a unique constraint to the combination of purchase_id and email - that is a way of stating that all combinations of customers and tracks must be unique. I'm not sure how you're going to indicate the unique constraint, but ultimately ER diagrams are about conveying a clear message - so as long as that's the case here, you should be OK.

Comment: @KurtHamilton so i cant show the unique constraint on the diagram but on the program? And i dont have to change anything about my diagram with that regard?

Comment: @log You should add it to the diagram if that's where you want to enforce uniqueness. It's up to you how you design your system.